# Need help with an android layout question

Tags: android

I need to have a linear Layout whose height is wrap_content, 
but how can I specify a child of this linear layout to stretch to its parent?

I tried 
    
                ... some other children ...

But this does not work.  The image does not scretch.

Answer (score 0):

wrap_content will stretch it to however big the content inside it is.
fill_parent will stretch it to the size of the parent container.

I would try fill_parent for the child.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

This should fill the parent with the child.

If you have multiple children within the parent and wish to leave no free space in the parent you should use

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight

> android:layout_weight" is the factor
>   the view will be stretched, when the
>   parent is larger than its childs in
>   sum.

Answer (score 0):

well i think this would not make so much sense.(i don't mean anything rude)

Your child layout can not stretch out to the parent's size because the size of the parent layout is only as big/small as your child class could- attempting to wrap around however big/small the child could get. Therefore, it's just basically like two people who can't decide who should decide. The other waits for the other's decision, and vice versa. Those layouts are dependent on each other's size, when the problem is there is not an established size to relate to then move on. You could maybe, reconsider your logic dude. ^^ I got so confused that by formulating an answer i got lost in confusion myself.

I hope this helps. This might help beginners in the future. This seems to be a fairly old question left unanswered.